# Sorting complex keys in couch db

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I am trying to learn the couch db sorting mechanism. 
I have read this [link](https://blog.couchbase.com/understanding-grouplevel-view-queries-compound-keys/) but when i test a small problem as the page suggested i am confused.

The page says

```
First thing of note and *very* important, even though this is an array output that seems like integers from the javascript Map function, they are not, each of those Index Keys are strings, and are ordered character by character as strings, including the brackets and commas, notice that all single digits are padded with zeros in front, and that is why the order is maintained. It's more like this, so we'll go ahead and keep the quote characters:
If you had the following Map output, notice that it is sorted differently than it would be if the Int parameters were actually Int's, in fact Index Keys are always strings.

[2012,”beer”,1]
null
[2012,”beer”,10]
null
[2012,”beer”,2]
null
Notice that the second “element” of the Index Key is ordered to be before the 3rd because of string compare, these are not integers. Back to the scheduled program…
```

So as i understand the complex key is considered a string even it has integer values in it(Including quotes and brackets) So i tried the following.

```
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.changeDate,doc.terminalUser.userName], doc._id);
}
```

And the result is.

```
{
    "total_rows": 466,
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "b1bf0dad-bf55-4e5f-86d7-830dd1aa3415",
            "key": [
                2,
                "test"
            ],
            "value": "b1bf0dad-bf55-4e5f-86d7-830dd1aa3415"
        },
        {
            "id": "ccab524a-ae6c-4131-a1af-bfccb5e70cff",
            "key": [
                3,
                "test"
            ],
            "value": "ccab524a-ae6c-4131-a1af-bfccb5e70cff"
        },
        {
            "id": "fa08d5e0-e430-4c9d-8340-d5db459ad67d",
            "key": [
                1524823966903,
                "test"
            ],
            "value": "fa08d5e0-e430-4c9d-8340-d5db459ad67d"
        },
        {
            "id": "aab5f103-6a65-4a19-9c1c-2749abec361b",
            "key": [
                1524824434308,
                "test"
            ],
            "value": "aab5f103-6a65-4a19-9c1c-2749abec361b"
        },
        {
            "id": "189a6d1c-d80d-4006-9852-4e17649b8d0e",
            "key": [
                1524824436016,
                "test"
            ],
            "value": "189a6d1c-d80d-4006-9852-4e17649b8d0e"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is, how come the entry with  key [2,"test"] is ordered before entry with key [1524823966903,"test"] if the compound key is considered a string altogether? It seems the integer is sorted as integer not a string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is tagged "couchdb" but you refer to Couchbase, which is a different thing ;)

In CouchDB, the sorting is not as you proffer in your question:

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"8b71d31c90836995f27d8c379442862c","key":[2012,"beer",1],"value":null},
{"id":"2fcf6ee7c3e4b4175c7ac2a95b70d7a3","key":[2012,"beer",2],"value":null},
{"id":"8b71d31c90836995f27d8c379444d5bd","key":[2012,"beer",10],"value":null}
]}
```

The above example shows that the third element of the array is treated as a number, giving the 1,2,10 sort order.

Detail of how views are ordered is explained in details [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/collation.html).